# Animating Steronets

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib

I have been looking around and have got to nowhere with this. I am trying to animate the poles on a stereonet diagram. However, the poles do not appear at the location that they should be in.

**Figure 1** is the animated pole plot while **Figure 2** is how the plot should be. I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to proceed with this?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import mplstereonet

fig, ax = mplstereonet.subplots()
fig2, ax1 = mplstereonet.subplots()

ax.grid(True)
ax1.grid(True)

# Assume a strike and dip with a random variance.
# Current values should plot the poles at either 0, 180
strike, dip = 90, 80
num = 10

strikes = strike + 10 * np.random.randn(num)
dips = dip + 10 * np.random.randn(num)

poles, = ax.pole([], [], 'o')

def init():
    poles.set_data([], [])
    return poles,

def animate(i):
    poles.set_data(strikes[:i], dips[:i])
    return poles,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames = len(strikes), interval = 100, blit=True, repeat=False)

poles1 = ax1.pole(strikes, dips, 'o') # This is how the final image should look like
plt.show()
```

Comment: So what *is*  the difference between those plots?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. They should be the same. I am trying to animate Figure 1 to reproduce the end result which should be Figure 2.

Comment: I understand that they *should* be the same. But in how far are they not the same?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was unable to find a correlation between the two. Sometimes points are plotted on Figure 1, sometimes nothing (Assumable caused by the random function). My wild guess is Figure 1 does not honor the Steronet projection.